# alert if selectbox value is empty

Tags: jquery

I need to check if the `select` box `option` value is empty, ie. the user has not selected anything. When he clicks on the button the system should display an `alert`.

I am trying this, but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.sedra1', function() {
    var m = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
      alert("Please choose some option");
      return;
    } else {
      $('.button > a').attr('href', 'accessories/tatreez/tatreez-view.php?id=' + m);
    }
  });
});
```

and this is the select box

```
    <select class="form-control embroiderys-value p-0 sedra1" required>
    
    <option selected disabled> Select </option>
    
    <?php
    
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM embroidery");
    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    echo '<option type="embroidery" img="' . $row['image'] . '" value="' . $row['id'] . '"> E' . $row['id'] . '</option>';
    
    }
    
    ?>
    </select>

</div>

</div>
<div class="col-3 p-0 button">

<a class="btn btn-primary" href=""  role="button">تفاصيل</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Is `0` the value of your "empty" state? (Including the mark-up for your `sedra1` element would be helpful)

Comment: I do that with no success

Answer (score 0):

You can check This solution.. for your code..
i think it will work for you..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '.sedra1', function() {
      var m=$(this).val();
if( m == ''){
    alert("Please choose some option");
     return;
}else{
    alert(m);//you can put your redirection
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sedra1">
<option value="select_1">Select 1</option>
<option value="">Select Empty</option>
<option value="Select_3">Select Value</option>
<option value="">Select Empty</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The code is working fine , but I need alert when click button

for example this is the button link 

<div class="col-3 p-0 button">

<a class="btn btn-primary" href=""  role="button">Details</a>

</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for your button click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '.yourclass', function() {
var m=$('#sedra1').val();
if( m == ''){
    alert("Please choose some option");
     return;
}else{
    alert(m); //you can put your redirection
      return;
}
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<select id="sedra1">
<option value="select_1">Select 1</option>
<option value="">Select Empty</option>
<option value="Select_3">Select Value</option>
<option value="">Select Empty</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-3 p-0 button">
<a class="btn yourclass btn-primary" href=""  role="button">تفاصيل</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great , but it worked only for 1 select box with unique id , how can I modify it to work with array contains multi select box ?